# URL privacy error when accessing URL without "www"

Tags: url, ssl-certificate, privacy

I migrated my website to Google Cloud and followed their tutorial for setting up an SSL certificate for the domain name. The site ([www.johnrpowell.work](http://www.johnrpowell.work)) loads fine on all browsers on both desktop and mobile.

When I attempt to load the site with just "johnrpowell.work" I get a SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN error from Firefox. It goes on to say that the certificate is only valid for "www.johnrpowell.work" and not "johnrpowell.work".

If it's valid for the full URL, should that include the one without "www"?

As explained in the details, I tried loading the website with "johnrpowell.work" and got privacy errors.

Answer (score 0):

> If it's valid for the full URL, should that include the one without "www"?

No. A certificate is only valid for what is explicitly said in the certificate, not for anything else. In your specific case the certificate is only valid for `www.johnrpowell.work`. If you want to have it valid for `johnrpowell.work` too you would have to get a certificate which covers both names or to get another certificate just for `johnrpowell.work` and configure your server accordingly to use it.

Comment: So why does "johnrpowell.work" load fine in every browser except Firefox?

Comment: @velojp: From looking at the network requests at the developer console it seems to be that Chrome automatically retries with the `www` prefix if the bare domain fails. Unfortunately browsers have a long history of silently but inconsistently working around common broken setups so that many users don't realize that their setup is broken ("it works for me, so it cannot be broken")

Comment: @velojp "in every browser" Care to extend which browsers you tried for real? Did you try on command line with things like `curl` and `wget` that don't bundle business decisions and will just get the raw results as needed for troubleshooting? Alternatively you have online troubleshooting tools, look at "SSL Qualys Labs". But it sees now a certificate with both names (with and without `www`) in SAN extension, so you might have just been too impatient and things corrected themselves afterwards.